# Excel vba, make SUMIF with dynamic range criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code in VBA do some automated tasks. Sheet1 is a form and the Sheet2 is a database where this data are stored. 
I would like to have also a `Button` when pressed to do a SUMIF in the last row.

```
SUMIF(Column containing search values, value to search for, column conaintining items to add)
```

My Code is as below

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet


Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataBase")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")
Set rngr = ws2.Range("C17")
Set rngs = ws2.Range("C18")
Set rngt = ws2.Range("C19")
Set rngu = ws2.Range("C20")
Set rngy = ws2.Range("C21")
Set rngw = ws2.Range("C24")
Set rngz = ws2.Range("C25")


h = ws2.Range("C1")
i = ws2.Range("C2")
j = ws2.Range("C3")
tot1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
tot2 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
tot3 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
tot4 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
tot = "=SUM(RC[-16]+RC[-10]+RC[-4]+RC[-1])"
k = ws2.Range("C5")
l = ws2.Range("C6")
m = ws2.Range("C7")
N = ws2.Range("C8")
f = ws2.Range("C11")
o = ws2.Range("C12")
p = ws2.Range("C13")
G = ws2.Range("C15")
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngr, ws2.Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngs, ws2.Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
t = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngt, ws2.Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
u = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngu, ws2.Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngy, ws2.Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
w = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngw, ws2.Range("E25:F26").Value, 2, False)
Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngz, ws2.Range("E25:F26").Value, 2, False)


lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
last_day = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
col_search = ws1.Range("A3", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
col_contain = ws1.Range("G3", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

ws1.Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( col_search, "=" & last_day, col_contain)
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 2) = h
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 3) = i
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 4) = j
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 5) = k
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 6) = l
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 8) = N
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 9) = tot1
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 9).Font.Bold = True
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 10) = f
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 11) = o
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 12) = p
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 13) = G
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 15) = tot2
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 15).Font.Bold = True
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 16) = r
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 17) = s
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 18) = t
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 19) = u
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 20) = y
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 21) = tot3
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 21).Font.Bold = True
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 22) = w
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 23) = Z
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 24) = tot4
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 24).Font.Bold = True
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 25) = tot
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 25).Font.Bold = True


Dim TargetColumns As Variant
Dim SourceCells As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rAddToCell As Range
Dim x As Long

TargetColumns = Array(20, 23) 'Column numbers to place into.
Set SourceCells = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Emails").Range("C22,C26")

'Look at each cell in turn.
For Each rCell In SourceCells

    'Find the last cell in the correct column.
    Set rAddToCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataBase"), CLng(TargetColumns(x)))

    'If there's already a comment then delete it first
    'Then add value from SourceCell into comment in Target column.
    With rAddToCell
        If HasComment(rAddToCell) Then
            .ClearComments
        End If
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:=rCell.Value
    End With

    x = x + 1
Next rCell

End Sub
```

The value to search for will be the last date so practically from what I have is

```
last_day = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

My actual format of SUMIF is wrong as I am not getting the result wanted. Maybe my logic is wrong or the code itself is wrong

```
ws1.Cells(lastRow, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(col_search, last_day, col_contain)
```

Error:

```
Run-time error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Any suggestion is welcome and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
last_day = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
```

otherwise you get the row number of the last used row and not its value.

**Additionally you mixed up `SumIf` and `SumIfs` which have different syntax order.**

---

#### SumIfs (multiple criteria)

And according to [WorksheetFunction.SumIfs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumifs) the syntax is

```
SumIfs(RangeToSum, Criteria_range1, Criteria1, Criteria_range2, Criteria2, …)
```

so I believe you need to switch the parameters and add a `"=" &` in the criteria

```
SumIfs(col_contain, col_search, "=" & last_day)
```

- `col_contain` = column to sum
- `col_search` = column to test against criteria

---

#### SumIf (single criteria)

Or you use the [WorksheetFunction.SumIf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.SumIf), where the syntax is

```
SumIf(Criteria_range, Criteria, RangeToSum)
```

Any you can use

```
SumIf( col_search, "=" & last_day, col_contain)
```

---

Note that I recommend to reduce the code a bit and remove the unnecessary variables. Also use meaningful variable names like `wsDB` and `wsEmails` which are much easier to read and understand than meaningless numbered variables or single letter variables like `a`, `b`, `c` …

Also it is a good practice to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all variables properly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub YourProcedureName()
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataBase")

    Dim wsEmails As Worksheet
    Set wsEmails = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")

    'm = wsEmails.Range("C7") 'was not used at all

    With wsDB
        Dim NextFreeRow As Long
        NextFreeRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Dim Last_Day As String
        Last_Day = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value

        Dim Col_Search As Range
        Col_Search = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Dim Col_Contain As Range
        Col_Contain = .Range("G3", .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With wsEmails
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Col_Search, "=" & Last_Day, Col_Contain)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 1).Value = Date
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 2) = .Range("C1")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 3) = .Range("C2")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 4) = .Range("C3")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 5) = .Range("C5")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 6) = .Range("C6")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 8) = .Range("C8")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 9) = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 9).Font.Bold = True
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 10) = .Range("C11")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 11) = .Range("C12")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 12) = .Range("C13")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 13) = .Range("C15")
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 15) = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 15).Font.Bold = True
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 16) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C17"), .Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 17) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C18"), .Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 18) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C19"), .Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C20"), .Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C21"), .Range("E18:F19").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 21) = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 21).Font.Bold = True
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 22) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C24"), .Range("E25:F26").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 23) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("C25"), .Range("E25:F26").Value, 2, False)
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 24) = "=SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 24).Font.Bold = True
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 25) = "=SUM(RC[-16]+RC[-10]+RC[-4]+RC[-1])"
        wsDB.Cells(NextFreeRow, 25).Font.Bold = True
    End With


    Dim TargetColumns As Variant
    TargetColumns = Array(20, 23) 'Column numbers to place into.

    Dim SourceCells As Range
    Set SourceCells = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Emails").Range("C22,C26")

    Dim x As Long

    'Look at each cell in turn.
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In SourceCells

        'Find the last cell in the correct column.
        Dim rAddToCell As Range
        Set rAddToCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataBase"), CLng(TargetColumns(x)))

        'If there's already a comment then delete it first
        'Then add value from SourceCell into comment in Target column.
        With rAddToCell
            If HasComment(rAddToCell) Then
                .ClearComments
            End If
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Text Text:=rCell.Value
        End With

        x = x + 1
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Additionally I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all your variables properly.

Comment: I am getting an error in the range definition `col_search = ws1.Range("A3", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` I guess that this is the wrong code of range definition. Can you help me out to define this range from the `"A3"` to the last cell in the column `A`

Comment: @fallcoshkoder Without seeing the declaration and initialization of your variables it's hard to tell what's wrong. Therefore please edit your original question and add the complete code part in the end of your question that you use right now. Also include the error message you get.

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ is something in this code, I have the columns `A` and `G` filled the `A` with Dates and the `G` with values I want to select all the `A` from `A3` and below until it reach the last row. `ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and this is the `range` of `SUMIF` criteria is `last_day = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value` as you helped me with the  `Value` and the `sum_range` will be inserted in the last row of `G`  `ws1.Cells(lastRow, 7).Value=SUMIF...`

Comment: No the code is correct, so the issue must be somewhere else. Please provide exactly all the information I asked for in my last comment, or I cannot help you. I need the complete relevant code part (including all variable definitions) and the error message (in your original question above).

Comment: Code Updated as requested

Comment: 2 things: • `Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet` only declares `ws2 As Worksheet` but `ws1` as `Variant`. You must declare a type for **every** variable `Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet`. • You need to specify the worksheet for **every** `Range`, `Rows` etc so add `ws1.` before the second range object `ws1.Range("A3", ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Comment: Now is working but I am getting a `#VALUE` instead of the `SUM` of that column! Weird. Anyway thank you for the help maybe is something else wrong